# Using multiple types or indexes in Elasticsearch php API

Tags: php, api, search, types, elasticsearch

I want to query multiple types and indices using **Elasticsearch PHP API**. but I don't Know how.
should I pass an array of types and indices to `$params` ? :

```
$params['index'] = $index;//array of indices
$params['type']  = $types;//array of types
$params['body']  = $q;//query body
//request elasticsearch for matched documents
$results = $client->search($params);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just add them as a **string** to `$params` :

```
$params['index'] = "index1,index2";// a comma-separated list of index names, without any extra space
$params['type']  = "type1, type2";//array of types
$params['body']  = $q;//query body
//request elasticsearch for matched documents
$results = $client->search($params);
```

Comment: I know this is old, but something I just ran into with this is... it is VERY important you do not have a space after the comma in index value! It'll just crash it.